# SSRS Caching and/or Snapshot

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am fairly new to SSRS reports so I am looking for guidance.  I have SSRS reports that have 3 visible parameters:  Manager, Director, and VP.  The report will display data based on the parameters selected.  Initially, the report was taking a very long time to load and my research led me to creating a snapshot of the report.

The initial load of the report is really quick (~5 secs) but the parameters are set to "Select All" in all sections.  When the report is later filtered to say, only 1 VP, the load time can vary anywhere between 20 to 90 seconds.  Because this report will be used by all aspects of management within the organization, load time is critical.

Is it possible to load the filtered data quicker?  Is there anything I can do?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the database indexed properly? Is there an index on the column that the parameter is compared to?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty broad efficiency issue. One of the big questions is whether or not the query takes a long time to run in the database or just in SSRS. Ideally you would start with optimizing the query and indexing, but that's not always enough. So the work has to be done somewhere, all you can do is shift the work to be done before the report is run. Here are a couple options:

**Caching**

1. Turn on caching for the report.
2. Schedule a subscription to run with each possible value for the parameter. This will cause the report to still load quickly once an individual is specified.

**Intermediate Table**

1. Schedule a SQL stored procedure to aggregate and index the data in a new table in your database.
2. Point the report to run from this data for quick reads.

Each option has it's pros and cons because you have to balance where the data preparation work is done. Sometimes you have to try a few options to see what works best for your situation.

Comment: One thing I should have mentioned is that data is being pulled from multiple views in the database.  Some queries have parameters in them (1-3).  There are about 7 datasets pulling in data for this report.  Would this slow the report in any instance?

Comment: Having views or multiple datasets is not inherently bad. But when you add complexity, it makes it more difficult to narrow down the bottlenecks. I would still suggest looking into the two options I mentioned. There should be an understanding that large amounts of complex data won't be live. It may have to be prepared overnight or on some regular schedule.

Comment: Caching is a great option but it only gives me the option to cache a set of parameters.  In this instance "Select All" for all 3 parameters.  I tried to schedule a subscription but it would only allow me to deliver the file in a particular format.  If I select a temp location, would it still cache my data?  It does become a hassle given there will be so many managers, directors, and VP's to choose from.

Comment: You can select a `NULL` delivery option for subscriptions so it just caches them. You can use a data-driven subscription to provide multiple parameter values. It will run a copy of the report for each row of data. If there are too many combinations, then memory becomes an issue.